# How can I suppress subsequent pipelines emails in Gitlab CI in case of a series of failed jobs?

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci, email, gitlab-api

I've got a pipeline that logs in and logs out off a web-application every 5 minutes to ensure that the apps backend works, the database is up...

There occurred a problem that was not even related to the app directly, and my boss was bombarded with email-notifications. Is it possible to limit the emails that notify of a series of broken pipelines to only one, and suppress all subsequent emails until the pipeline has been fixed?

It seems that the editor for "Pipelines emails" is rather limited and doesn't support this directly. However, this option exists in Jenkins, and I'm wondering if someone figured out a solution or a workaround to achieve this in Gitlab CI. (Is it possible to script something like this in the ".gitlab-ci.yml"-file?)

Comment: Please note that I've posted a copy of the question @ https://forum.gitlab.com/t/41364

Comment: For details, please see the feature proposal: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/246754